# Creating a normally distributed sample where data adds to a number

Tags: python, random, normal-distribution

I want to generate a sample of n data points (floating values), such that they are approximately normally distributed and their sum is very close to S. I am using python function random.normalvariate(sampleMean, standardDeviatnion) to generate the set, but I am not sure how to guarantee that the data points add up to S. How could I go about it?

Comment: To get a fixed sum, you only have `n-1` degrees of freedom. Generate `n-1` data points, then add the difference between their sum and `S` as the last point. (Then shuffle, to randomize the position of the special data point.)

Comment: For it to be normally distributed would you also not need a standard deviation and mean to define the distribution?

Comment: And how sum would be defined? For normal distribution, sum of numbers divided by N, is approximately mean. Either you fix mean, but then sum would be better to be defined as mean*N, or you fix mean, and sum should be mean/N. You don't have much freedom here, please clarify what exactly do you want.

Comment: Sum is defined as adding all data points. In the context of my problem, I am generating population for each region of the city knowing the city has S people.